# Can I use a US PlayStation Network card if I live in a different country?

Tags: psn

I'm trying to buy some DLC for my games, but since I'm living outside the USA I can't use my credit card to add funds to my PSN wallet. My country was not listed when I created a PlayStation Network account, so now my only hope is a **PlayStation Network Card**.

I have created a separate US PSN account for purchases; can I use a US-based **PlayStation Network Card** to add funds to my PSN wallet? Has anyone tried this before?

**UPDATE**

I tried is and it's working. Bought a digital PSN card from http://www.maximuscards.com/ they are really fast.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it personally, but a few minutes research via Google reveals that it is indeed possible.

Comment: @MMRUser: Don't forget you can answer your own questions seeing how you figured out the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have done that myself.

Since i'm not from USA, i created a different account i buy credit for it to buy some stuff. The only restriction is that in order to play or use the stuff you buy with that account, is that both are as users in the same PS3 system.

This is necessary since it has to check for the user who bought it, but you can freely use the games/stuff for your main account

Comment: If I buy stuff with the "fake" account that lives in USA will it be available for all users on the PS3 or just for the user with the "fake" account. Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up another Profile and configure it as a US account, that's what I've done so I can buy things off the US PSN store which are regionally restricted here in my country. Also so I can buy and redeem cheaper 4SaleUSA.com bought PSN codes